# Angular ngFor conflict issue with datatables.net removing pagination, sorting and search features

Tags: angular, datatables, ngfor

I am creating a web application in angular and I'm really new and hoping to get some guidance.

**html table**

```html
<table datatable class="table">
   <thead class="fs-5 text-primary">
      <tr>
         <th>Title</th>
         <th>Authors</th>
         <th>Reviewer</th>
         <th>Last Updated</th>
         <th>Status</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr class="align-middle fw-bold fs-5" *ngFor="let proposal of proposals">
         <td>{{proposal.title}}</td>
         <td>{{proposal.authors}}</td>
         <td>{{proposal.reviewer}}</td>
         <td>{{proposal.timestamp}}</td>
         <td><button class="btn btn-dark rounded-0">
               View
            </button></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

**components.ts**

```js
export class SubmissionResearchComponent implements OnInit {
   proposals: IProposal[] = [];
   private proposalsUrl = './assets/proposals.json';
   constructor(private service: MeecoServiceService) { }
   ngOnInit() {
      this.service.getProposals().subscribe((proposals: IProposal[]) => {
         this.proposals = proposals;

      });
   }
}
```

**service.ts**

```js
export class MeecoServiceService {
   constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
   private proposalsUrl = './assets/proposals.json';
   getProposals(): Observable<IProposal[]> {
      return this.http.get<IProposal[]>(this.proposalsUrl);
   }
}
```

I already tried this https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/angular-way but it seems this is deprecated already.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PMOOUKxPcBDcJDgOGbpL7Q4atE_eEpe1/view?usp=sharing

current result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bihanbsgsoQ&t=4s

After a lot of research, finally I get the solution here. Problem solved.

### component.ts

```
 dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
  dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dtOptions = {
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
    };
    this.Proposals();

  }

  Proposals() {
    this.service.getProposals().subscribe(res => {
      this.proposals = res;
      this.dtTrigger.next(null);

    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.dtTrigger.unsubscribe();
  }
```

### html

```
<table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" class="table" >
            <thead>
                <tr class="fs-5 text-primary">
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Authors</th>
                    <th>Reviewer</th>
                    <th>Timestamp</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let proposal of proposals" class="fw-normal fs-5">
                    <td>{{proposal.title}}</td>
                    <td>{{proposal.authors}}</td>
                    <td>{{proposal.reviewer}}</td>
                    <td>{{proposal.timestamp}}</td>
                    <td>{{proposal.status}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

service.ts

```
getProposals(): Observable<IProposal[]> {
return this.http.get<IProposal[]>(this.proposalsUrl);
```

}

---